# Heroku webapp-runner --enable-naming

Tags: java, maven, heroku, embedded-tomcat-7, webapp-runner

I've been facing with a combersome task: deploying a spring project ( using JNDI ).

Right now the problem is related to the webapp-runner option "enable-naming". 
My datasources are declared by jndi - using tomcar context.xml.
When i feed webapp-runner with the option referred i get this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException:   
**Unknown option: --enable-naming** 
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:723)
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:275)
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:258)
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.(JCommander.java:203)
at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:74)
```

I've been digging the webapp-runner code and saw this condition:

```
if (commandLineParams.enableNaming ||
commandLineParams.enableBasicAuth ||
commandLineParams.tomcatUsersLocation != null) {
tomcat.enableNaming();
}
```

So i've tried with --enable-basic-auth option and my app runs just fine... The problem is i don't want basic-auth in my site.

I'm using maven heroku-maven-plugin, and as
WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS: --context-xml tomcat-heroku-server-conf/context.xml --enable-naming

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option was added in webapp-runner 8.0.33.1, but at the time of this writing the [Heroku CLI WAR deployment plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli-deploy) and the [Heroku Maven plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin) default to version 8.0.30.2 of webapp-runner.

You can set the version like this for the CLI:

```
$ heroku deploy:war --webapp-runner 8.0.33.3 path/to/app.war
```

Or like this for Maven:

```
$ mvn heroku:deploy-war -Dheroku.webappRunnerVersion=8.0.33.3
```

I maintain webapp-runner and those plugins, and I'll update them to use 8.0.33.3 shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I've received a similar response from heroku support codefinger

For future notice i've added

```
<webappRunnerVersion>8.0.33.1</webappRunnerVersion>
```

to the heroku-maven-plugin in the pom.xml file.

So the heroku-maven-plugin is now:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
     <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.1</version>           
     <configuration>               
         <includes>
             <include>tomcat-heroku-server-conf/</include>
         </includes>
         <jdkVersion>1.8</jdkVersion>
         <configVars>
            <CATALINA_OPTS>-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx1024M -Ddatabase.url=** -Ddatabase.user=** -Ddatabase.password=** -Ddatabase.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</CATALINA_OPTS>
             <JAVA_OPTS></JAVA_OPTS>
          </configVars>      
          <webappRunnerVersion>8.0.33.1</webappRunnerVersion>
          <warFile>admin/target/admin.war</warFile>
      </configuration>
```